# How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa with python?

Tags: python, datetime, unix

A [unix timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/) is an `int` which gives the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, UTC.

Is there a way to convert the .NET timestamp to unix timestamp using python ? or can this only be done in C# ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Similar question: [How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa#)  this contains how to do this in C I am looking for a way to do this in python 34

Comment: @Schizo OP wants the python version. look into [`strptime` from datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Comment: the heading "convert unix timestamp to datetime" seems not to mach the question body "convert the .NEW timestamp to unix timestamp".  Which one is the question?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to convert the .NET timestamp to unix timestamp using python?

```
posix_epoch_as_dotnet = 621355968000000000

# convert .NET timestamp to POSIX timestamp
posix_timestamp = (130900894153614080 - posix_epoch_as_dotnet) // 10**7
```

It is easy to convert between a datetime object that represents time in UTC and the timestamps:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dotnet_epoch = datetime(1, 1, 1)
posix_epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
utc_time = dotnet_epoch + timedelta(microseconds=dotnet_timestamp//10)
utc_time = posix_epoch + timedelta(seconds=posix_timestamp)
```

and back:

```
posix_timestamp = (utc_time - posix_epoch) // timedelta(seconds=1)
dotnet_timestamp = 10 * (utc_time - dotnet_epoch) // timedelta(microseconds=1)
```

See [`totimestamp()` function on how to implement `// timedelta()` on older Python versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).