# How can I convert TimeStamp to a date in c#?

Tags: c#, date, timestamp

How can I convert a timestamp given by `Event.Timestamp` to a Date.

For example I have TimeStamp=72052934740143

I am working with Xamarin.ANdroid. And I need to make this conversion even outside the algorithm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but Timestamps represents a duration of time, DateTime represents a point in time. Without specifying a starting point in time your question is unanswerable

Comment: Timestamp gives the duration of time since  Jan 01 1970.

Comment: I am not an expert but I think that this is true if we are talking about Unix Timestamp. Instead I think you are dealing with the time passed from the system startup. Indeed, if you look at the answer below, adding Milliseconds or Ticks you get improbable values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read : https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/timestamp/

> The value of the Timestamp property is an int, rather than a DateTime
>   object.  The integer represents the number of milliseconds since the
>   last reboot.  When the value grows too large to store in the integer
>   object, it resets to 0.  This happens every 24.9 days.

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    dt.AddMilliseconds(e.Timestamp - Environment.TickCount);

    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Key DOWN at: {0}", dt.ToString("h:mm:ss.FFF tt")));
}
```

or in short:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(e.Timestamp - Environment.TickCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
double TimeStamp = 72052934740143;
ateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddMilliseconds(TimeStamp);
```

Comment: Looks like number is ticks not milliseconds. DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("1/1/16").AddTicks(72052934740143L);