# Convert string to unix timestamp and check if it is older than 8h

Tags: powershell, unix, timestamp

I get a timestamp like below as a string:

> 1485661375

I need to parse it to unix timestamp and check if it is older than 8h.

Comment: And what time is 1485661375 representing??

Comment: @Svekke It's a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), the number of seconds since the Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00).

Comment: Please do not edit an answer into a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[datetimeoffset]::FromUnixTimeSeconds('1485661375') -gt (get-date).AddHours(-8)
```

requires .NET 4.6, for converting without .NET 4.6 you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa).

Comment: Thanks. For me worked marked thread