# Determine DateTime format for API C#

Tags: c#, json, datetime

I am reading an API documentation that says I have to pass current time to it in following format:

```
{
   "date": "\/Date(1508262132936)\/"
}
```

And the one-line explanation of this format says: "Date in UTC format".  I tried passing `DateTime.Now; DateTime.Now.UtcNow; DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();`  but all of those output BadRequest reply. What is the correct format here?

Comment: To be clear, you're calling an **external** API, and they said what format to send it?

Comment: I am calling an external API (HTTP REST), the only explanation I have is "Date in UTC format" (what they told me)

Comment: That format is far from being related to UTC.

Comment: The format they are asking for is sometimes known as "Microsoft format".  How to generate it depends on which JSON library you are using, e.g. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm.   I suspect Microsoft's `JavaScriptSerializer` class generates that format by default, hence the name "Microsoft format".

Comment: I am using RestSharp's  built-in JSON serializer

Comment: @astralmaster - I bet googling for "RestSharp json date format" will give you some hints.

Comment: @Joe that's the first thing I tried but they all output different formats including the ones I posted in my question

Comment: @astralmaster - you might consider using the Newtonsoft library, which is very popular.  Otherwise, you can generate milliseconds since 01/01/1970 00:00, and manually decorate it.

Comment: You can check how [NewtonSoft.Json does it](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/92d170a0783bc962f52faf02acfcecbe21d3b683/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/DateTimeUtils.cs#L646)

Comment: @Joe Am I right to assume that the API engine uses some 3rd party library as well? Since this doesn't seem to be a 'standard' ?

Comment: sadly I only have javascript code that goes the other way ... I think Joe and Camilo Terevinto have the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a Unix epoch time, use the `ToUnixTimeSeconds` method on DateTimeOffset:

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
new DateTimeOffset(date).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
```

Comment: This still doesn't use UTC

Comment: Just use any date :)

Comment: I am unable to find `ToUnixTimeSeconds()` method for the DateTimeOffset

Comment: Turns out to use `ToUnixTimeSeconds()` you project must target .NET Framework 4.6 or higher. Are there no alternatives?

Comment: yeah only 4.6+ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/?view=netframework-4.6&term=ToUnixTimeSeconds

Comment: You'll have to write your own conversion if you're targetting a lower version, but here's the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa