# How to convert json response date string into c# date format?

Tags: c#, json

I have json string like "1536476400000" and i convert into "yyyy-MM-dd" format using C#. please help me

Comment: is 1536476400000 a timestamp in milliseconds?

Comment: i don't know which format just its json response and it convert into online it will display date

Comment: well i already tried it. And its a timestamp in millisecond dated sept. 9 2018. refer to this topic. it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Comment: @John i test it using https://www.epochconverter.com, no problem and it's the time for yesterday.

Comment: Thanks to all, i got solution.. Thanks you all again...

Answer (score 5):

Solved Answer is...

```
String offset = "1536476400000";
double spotQuoteEffDate = double.Parse(offset );
TimeSpan spotQuoteEffDateTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(spotQuoteEffDate);
DateTime spotQuote = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) + spotQuoteEffDateTime;
```

Output is...

```
spotQuote = 9/9/2018 7:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer below code,

```
  TimeSpan s = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(double.Parse("1536476400000" ));
  DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) + s;
  Console.writeline(String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",dt));
```