# Combine List<> but with logic for each match

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list very similar to this (But example is simplified):

```
public class TimeEntry
{
    public int entrydate { get; set; } //UNIX Timestamp
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string timespent { get; set; } //Be aware this is a string, not an int or date - [hh]:mm (Hours can go above 24)
}

List<TimeEntry> entryTable = new List<TimeEntry>();


//This layout is fictional and just a representation of my List<TimeEntry>
[entrydate: "1540364988", name: "Time1", timespent: "0:30"],
[entrydate: "1540304400", name: "Time2", timespent: "0:25"],
[entrydate: "1540307400", name: "Time1", timespent: "0:10"],
[entrydate: "1540300010", name: "Time3", timespent: "0:40"],
[entrydate: "1540365000", name: "Time1", timespent: "1:10"],
[entrydate: "1540367500", name: "Time3", timespent: "0:20"],
[entrydate: "1540354500", name: "Time4", timespent: "0:30"]
```

I would like to combine each entry so they have a total per day for each unique *name* entry.

So for example

```
[entrydate: "1540364988", name: "Time1", timespent: "0:30"],
[entrydate: "1540307400", name: "Time1", timespent: "0:10"],
[entrydate: "1540365000", name: "Time1", timespent: "1:10"]
```

would become

```
[entrydate: "1540252800", name: "Time1", timespent: "0:10"],
[entrydate: "1540339200", name: "Time1", timespent: "1:40"]
```

How would I do this in an efficient way? We're talking about 450,000 records, I'm thinking about just using a loop, but having a loop run 450,000 times where in each loop we need to run through all the records we've stored already, just to see if we should count up instead of add a new record sounds inefficient and slow.

No need for full completed code, but I'd love to hear someones opinion or solution on this. Although every little bit of help is appreciated
Thanks

EDIT:

Since the question got put on hold for not enough information, here is some more information about my issue:

**Goal:** Combine each entry from the same *day* that share the same *name*

The timestamp is in *UTC* and a day would be from *00:00:00 to 23:59:99.*

Comment: What's the relation between your input and your desired output, it seems unclear to me. Also what have tried so far?

Comment: what type of format is the entrydate?

Comment: Check the [linq.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) it uses hashing and its performance is close to O(n) - no need for 2 nested loops O(n^2)

Comment: I don't understand how in your example you would decide to combine the first and third entry but leave the second alone, what's the criteria?

Comment: @S.Akbari As said above, I want to combine the timespent from entries that happen on the same day. The result will be 2 rows instead of 3, as out of the 3 rows there are only 2 unique dates. I've not tried anything that had any note worthy results, other then just a loop that become a performance issue

Comment: @Jaques UNIX Timestamp, editted my post

Comment: Start by [working with `DateTime`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/250400/5265292) (you should probably use `ToUniversalTime` instead of `ToLocalTime`)...

Comment: Can you describe `timespent` a bit more... I guess I could answer then question when it is reopened, but I don't know whether I look at `minutes:seconds`, `hours:minutes` or some different string format...

Comment: @grek40 I'm very sorry, I totally overlooked the explanation for it! We're looking at [hh]:mm, so the hours will count up past 24 but the minutes turn over after 59 into a new hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to convert your `entrydate` to a whole-day value, group your entries by name and whole-day, then compute the timespent for each group.

The following code does all that.

1. convert `entrydate` is done by `TrimUnixTimestampToDate`

   - I took the basic approach from [How can I convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa/250400#250400)
2. grouping is done with the linq `GroupBy` function using an aggregate key of name and date
   computing the timespent is done by converting each `timespent` to a `TimeSpan` via `ToTimeSpan` and adding them all together with `AddTimespans`

   - note I did not write proper error handling for the case of ill-formatted timespent values. You have to decide if you need it
3. the resulting timespan is converted back to string
4. a new object is created for the aggregate data

/

```
List<TimeEntry> TimeEntryProcessing()
{
    var entries = new List<TimeEntry>
    {
        new TimeEntry{ entrydate = 1540364988, name = "Time1", timespent = "0:30"},
        new TimeEntry{ entrydate = 1540304400, name = "Time2", timespent = "0:25"},
        new TimeEntry{ entrydate = 1540307400, name = "Time1", timespent = "0:10"},
        new TimeEntry{ entrydate = 1540300010, name = "Time3", timespent = "0:40"},
        new TimeEntry{ entrydate = 1540365000, name = "Time1", timespent = "1:10"},
        new TimeEntry{ entrydate = 1540367500, name = "Time3", timespent = "0:20"},
        new TimeEntry{ entrydate = 1540354500, name = "Time4", timespent = "0:30"}
    };

    return entries
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.name, date = TrimUnixTimestampToDate(x.entrydate) })
        .Select(x =>
        {
            var time = AddTimespans(x.Select(y => ToTimeSpan(y.timespent)));
            return new TimeEntry
            {
                entrydate = x.Key.date,
                name = x.Key.name,
                timespent = $"{(int)time.TotalHours}:{time.Minutes}"
            };
        })
        // in case you need an order... you didn't mention it
        .OrderBy(x => x.entrydate).ThenBy(x => x.name)
        .ToList();
}

TimeSpan AddTimespans(IEnumerable<TimeSpan> enumerable)
{
    return new TimeSpan(enumerable.Sum(x => x.Ticks));
}

TimeSpan ToTimeSpan(string timespent)
{
    var parts = timespent.Split(':');
    return new TimeSpan(int.Parse(parts[0]), int.Parse(parts[1]), 0);
}

int TrimUnixTimestampToDate(int entrydate)
{
    DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return (int)dtDateTime.AddSeconds(entrydate).Date.Subtract(dtDateTime).TotalSeconds;
}
```

Comment: My bad for taking a while to respond, this works like a charm! Had to change a few things as the code woudn't compile (some minor errors, nothing big) but you helped me out big time.