# How to Convert Timestamp to DateTime?

Tags: c#, firefox, timestamp, epoch

I want to convert epoch to human readable date and vice versa.
I want to write something similar to [link](https://www.epochconverter.com) in C#.

Converting the date in the places.sqlite file in Firefox to a DateTime.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //1540787809621000
    string epoch = "1540787809621000";
}

private string epoch2string(int epoch) {
    return 
        new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
            .AddSeconds(epoch)
            .ToShortDateString(); 
}
```

int size Not enough I try long epoch but not work

Comment: please share your c# code

Comment: and what "not working" means.

Comment: [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(Int64) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTimeOffset_FromUnixTimeSeconds_System_Int64_)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not good at English. But I will try to communicate.
new post Below

Comment: @ThanawutPadermwong, when you have to add information to your question use the [edit] button on the bottom of your post. The answer box are for answer not for clarification.

Comment: Ok for clarification  I will follow the instructions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your time is a Unix time in microseconds.

If you are using .Net 4.6 or later, you can convert this to a `DateTime` as follows.

```
long time = 1540787809621000; // Unix time in microseconds.

time /= 1000; // Divide by 1,000 because we need milliseconds, not microseconds.

DateTime result = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(time).DateTime;

Console.WriteLine(result); // Prints 29/10/2018 04:36:49 (UK format)
```