# How can I convert the number of seconds since Jan 1st 1970 into a datetime value?

Tags: c#

I have a number that is the number of seconds since January 1st 1970. It was created with this:

```
 var utcNow = (int) Math.Truncate(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds);
```

Now  need to convert that number to a date in string form like this:

```
Tue, Jan 15, 2019
```

Can someone give me some suggestions on how I can do this.  I think I can format it myself but I need a suggestion on how to convert the integer utcNow into a datetime first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static readonly DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
...
DateTime time = epoch.AddSeconds(utcNow);
```

You can also use this in reverse:

```
var seconds = (time - epoch).TotalSeconds;
```

(which gives a `double`, but you can cast it to `int` or `long` etc)

Answer (score 3):

Some answer are already given, and work. But this is, I believe, the most elegant way of doing it. I'm using [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(int64)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTimeOffset_FromUnixTimeSeconds_System_Int64_)

```
DateTimeOffset dt = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(utcNow);
```

And now you can convert it into a DateTime Struct with help of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset) blog entry

Answer (score 2):

Substract the given time from current time and it gives timespan instance, from that you can get total seconds

```
        var fromDate = new DateTime(1970,1 ,1);
        var diffrance = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(fromDate);
        Console.WriteLine(diffrance.TotalSeconds);
```