# Is there a term for this type of date and how do I convert it?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am given a date like these:

1555473600
1555560000

Is there a term for this type of date and how do I convert it to something like 12/28/2018 1:00 pm for example?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like an Unix timestamps. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/249760/4685428) for more details

Comment: Are you referring to Epoch maybe? Basically its the number of milliseconds from a specified `DateTime` like `1970-1-1`. If that is not it you will have to provide some more context like the origin of this data.

Comment: @AleksAndreev You are right, it is a Unix timestamp. I just reviewed the documentation.

Comment: @Igor Thank you, I believe you are right. Where does the 1970-1-1 come from? Is that standard?

Comment: @ErocM yes this is standard. Read more about [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) on wiki

Comment: @Igor - https://codeofmatt.com/please-dont-call-it-epoch-time/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.7.2) provides methods to convert to/from values based on the Unix epoch (1st January 1970, midnight UTC).

```
var dateTime1 = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1555473600);
var dateTime2 = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMillieconds(1555560000);
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks to be a serial time, formatted in unix time. It is defined as the number of seconds since the unix epoch (January 1, 1970 midnight UTC).

Here is a hypothetical function for converting a unix time to human readable string.

```
private string epoch2string(int epoch) {
   return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(epoch).ToShortDateString();
}
```

Now that you know what format that serial date is in, you can search the many posts discussing converting to/from unix time. Here is a useful link discussing unix time:

[epoch converter](https://www.epochconverter.com)