# How to serialize DateTimeOffset propety to (UTC) milliseconds using Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

**Please note that this is not about time conversion, but about converting JSON/C# types**

I am need serialize and deserialize an object with a property DateTimeOffset but her value need be in milliseconds format when serialized; when deserialize, convert it to DateTimeOffset again.
I came to this point:

```
public class JsonDateTimeOffsetAndMillisecondsConverter: JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var t = long.Parse((string)reader.Value);
        return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(t);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // How to write in json the datetime property as milliseconds?        }
}
```

But I not know how to serialize in milliseconds now. Can someone help me?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31588322/3181933). Ge the milliseconds and call `writer.WriteValue(milliseconds)`

Comment: This is not duplicated. Not is about time convertion, but JSON type convertion.

Comment: Then why is your question in the code _"// How to serialize DateTimeOffset propety to (UTC) milliseconds?"_?

Comment: The complet title of question is: How to serialize DateTimeOffset propety to (UTC) milliseconds using Newtonsoft.Json? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [method from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa/31588322#31588322), we can obtain the corresponding millisecond Unix epoch:

```
var valueDto = (DateTimeOffset)(DateTime)value;
var milliseconds = (valueDto).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

You then simply have to write the value:

```
writer.WriteValue(milliseconds);
```

Combining it, we get:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var valueDto = (DateTimeOffset)(DateTime)value;
    var milliseconds = (valueDto).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
    writer.WriteValue(milliseconds);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I am in doubt whether the method will preserve the standard serialization of the other properties of the class.

Comment: The `CanConvert` method only allows this to consider `DateTime` properties. If you don't want to register it against all `DateTime` properties, don't add it to your `JsonSerializerSettings`. Instead, decorate the property you want this applied to with a `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonDateTimeOffsetAndMillisecondsConverter))]` attribute.