# Convert Long to DateTime give false value

Tags: c#, datetime

I just tried to convert a date stored as a long value into a DateTime but it gives me the date `{2/01/0001 7:35:22 PM}` whereas it should be `{23/09/2019 4:30:23}` (GMT +10)

Here is the long value `1569220232761` created on initialising the object.
Here is the code that returns 2/01/0001

```
SeshStart = new DateTime(CurrentSession.startDate, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

With `CurrentSession.startDate` equal `1569220232761`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a *Unix Time*, not the number of *Ticks* (which would be orders of magnitudes larger)

<sub>*i.e `637,048,098,230,000,000` apposed to `1,569,220,232,761`*</sub>

[Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

> Unix time (also known as Epoch time, POSIX time, seconds
>   since the Epoch, or UNIX Epoch time) is a system for describing
>   a point in time. It is the number of seconds that have elapsed since
>   the Unix epoch, that is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970,

[DateTime(Int64)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int64_)

> Initializes a new instance of the DateTime structure to a specified
>   number of ticks.

Try something like this

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeToDateTime(long unixtime)
{
   var dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
   return dtDateTime.AddMilliseconds(unixtime).ToLocalTime();
}
```

Comment: Dope thanks ! Added it to my helpers thanks a lot
```SeshStart = DataHelpers.DateTimeHelper.DateFromUnixTime(CurrentSession.startDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are calling [`DateTime(Int64, DateTimeKind)` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int64_System_DateTimeKind_) and as stated;

> Parameters
>
> `ticks`
>
> Int64
>
> A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond
>   intervals that have elapsed **since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in
>   the Gregorian calendar**.

As a `Ticks`, `1569220232761` is equal to `Monday, 23 September 2019 06:30:32.761 GTM` and you can calculate your value exactly how explained on [How can I convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa) question.

Also be aware, with .NET 4.6 version, two method introduced as [`DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(Int64)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTimeOffset_FromUnixTimeSeconds_System_Int64_) and [`DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTimeOffset_ToUnixTimeSeconds).

Comment: Up vote, this is a really good answer, I always forget about those 2 methods, I'll have to update my libs