# How Can I Convert Json Datetime To Normal Date Time Format(dd.mm.yyyy)?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, string, datetime

How can I convert a Json DateTime string to normal date format(dd.mm.yyyy)?

```
    public JsonResult ProductListGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            var productListModel = new List<ProductListModel>();

            var products= ProductOperations.ProductListGetirDT(ExceptionCatcher);
            foreach (var item in products)
            {
                productListModel.Add(new ProductListModel()
                {
                    //...
                    ProductDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ProductDate ),
                   //:::
                });
            }

            return Json(productListModel , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        ...
```

17.12.2018 (I expect)

/Date(1549659600000)/ (Output)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Comment: I think this would answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format

Comment: I think your question may be the wrong way round. From the title it sounds like you're trying to deserialize a datetime from JSON, however the rest of your question reads like you're having trouble serilizing a DateTime to JSON. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(ProductDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TryParseExact` to convert the string date to DateTime

```
private static DateTime ParseDate(string providedDate)
{
    DateTime validDate;
    string[] formats = { "dd.MM.yyyy" };
    var dateFormatIsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
        providedDate,
        formats,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None,
        out validDate);
    return dateFormatIsValid ? validDate : DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

And call this method to parse the json date format

```
ProductDate = ParseDate(item.ProductDate)
```

Comment: This function doesnt work, it returns always false?

Comment: @ZeynepAydemir, I have tried with your example and it worked. `DateTime date = ParseDate("17.12.2018");`