# How to convert nanoseconds to local DateTimeOffset in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

How can I convert nanoseconds to `Datetimeoffset`?

I tried date time

```
long nanoseconds = 1449491983090000000;
DateTime epochTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
DateTime result1 = epochTime.AddTicks(nanoseconds / 100);

DateTime epochTimfe = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime result2 = epochTime.AddTicks(nanoseconds / 100);
```

Both `result1` and `result2` are giving me GMT time. i.e.,

> 12/7/2015 12:39:43 PM

I verified that from [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/)

Can anyone help me how to convert nanoseconds to `DateTimeOffset` ?

Comment: You can try to use `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` method, add look at this thread  [How can I convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Nanoseconds are a unit of time. DateTimeOffsets represent an instant in time (with an associated time zone). What you are asking is something like "I want to convert from km to location". If you peg a starting position and a direction (which isn't necessary for time, there's only one direction), you can do it, but you need a starting point (an epoch in time-speek). You can get a TimeSpan from nanoseconds pretty easily. If you add that to a starting dateTimeOffset, you should be off to the races

Comment: Alternatively, once you actually have a correct `DateTime` (by whatever method), you can simply pass it to the `DateTimeOffset` constructor and get the `.ToLocalTime()` of it. This requires that the `DateTimeKind` is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just construct an instance of `DateTimeOffset` in UTC, add the nanoseconds, then call `ToLocalTime` to get the local version.

```
long nanoseconds = 1449491983090000000;
var epochTime = new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
var utc = epochTime.AddTicks(nanoseconds / 100);
var local = utc.ToLocalTime();
```