# Can I strictly define "struct Timestamp" data type instead of "long" in c#?

Tags: c#, performance, memory, struct, unix-timestamp

I want to store a timestamps in memory (billions of values).
The main operations are read-to-memory and read-from-memory, no need in DateTime-specific methods.
For compatibility with other services, I want to use unix timestamp format in seconds (to avoid conversions).

So, I want to use special data type instead of just `long` in my code.

I found that I can not "make alias name" for simple data type like `long`, which I can fully use outside assembly.

So, I want to implement Timestamp as struct with single `long` field and some methods (ex, ToDateTime, some operator overloading, etc.), because structs are "non-reference data type" and they keep my memory.

**Is making a struct is bad idea?**

**Any alternatives** to make code strongly-typed, to redefine `Method (long, long)` to `Method (Timestamp, StepCount)`

Comment: *"I want to store a timestamps in memory (billions of values)"*;  how much mem do you have? (just wondering)

Comment: Struct is fine, I'm sure.

Comment: Let's forget about the number of values for a moment. Wrapping a 64-bit integer in a struct to provide timestamp-specific operations will be fine. *That's exactly what `DateTime` is.*

Comment: @madreflection, thanks. Just looked to DateTime sources. There is support for DateTimeKind (only 62 bits are used for timestamp and 2 bits for kind), which may be a headache in my case. I will use custom struct.

Comment: `DateTime` and Unix timestamps are framed differently (Christopher's answer explains how `DateTime` is framed in ticks) so go for it if that's what's right for you. Before you do, though, take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa) in case that handles it well enough for your needs.

Answer (score 5):

DateTime interally uses [Ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.8) as the value. Almost every other function call and property is just a *reinterpretation* of the Ticks value.

Ticks are way more granular then seconds, by 7 orders of magnitude.

"A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond, or 10 million ticks in a second.

The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 in the Gregorian calendar, which represents MinValue."

However the internal clock is not [actually that precise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime). `DateTime.Now` might only update every ~30 ms or less. For precise measurements, you would have to use the [StopWatch class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.0) instead.

Of course with **Billions** of values, it really becomes a question if you got the memory. The .NET Object Size, [memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases?redirectedfrom=MSDN#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2003) and array size limtis might get in the way. It might be better to store those values in a database and only look at parts of the list. Use heavy filtering in the query.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a radical alternative: there are actually some build in routines to do a proper conversion, I think containing some of the routines you're after.

From msdn:

```cs
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
      Console.WriteLine("{0} --> Unix Seconds: {1}", dto, dto.ToUnixTimeSeconds());

      dto = new DateTimeOffset(1969, 12, 31, 23, 59, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
      Console.WriteLine("{0} --> Unix Seconds: {1}", dto, dto.ToUnixTimeSeconds());

      dto = new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
      Console.WriteLine("{0} --> Unix Seconds: {1}", dto, dto.ToUnixTimeSeconds());
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//    1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM +00:00 --> Unix Seconds: 0
//    12/31/1969 11:59:00 PM +00:00 --> Unix Seconds: -60
//    1/1/1970 12:01:00 AM +00:00 --> Unix Seconds: 60
```

Or the counterpart:

```
public static DateTimeOffset FromUnixTimeSeconds (long seconds);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds?view=netcore-3.1

---

For this reason: yes, I think rebuilding a similar struct is a bad idea, because it's already been done. But I might be missing some context.

Comment: Bonus video: anti-do-it-yourself: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY