# How can i translate string timestamp to Date?

Tags: c#, timestamp

I has in string format, timestamp `1593339378252`, i need convert this, to a normal human date-`20.06.2020`
I try this code

```
var timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(dateFrom);

            // Format our new DateTime object to start at the UNIX Epoch
            System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            // Add the timestamp (number of seconds since the Epoch) to be converted
            dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(timestamp);
```

but if i try convert to int32,16,64 i get `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Comment: `DateTime dt = new DateTime(timestamp);` did you try this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your timestamp actually contains number of milliseconds, not seconds:

```
new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(1593339378252)
// on my machine - 28-Jun-20 10:16:18 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(yourValue);`

For more information, also look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: You's decision also helped, and it is have small code