# Modify column contents before transfer with SqlBulkCopy

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, sqlbulkcopy

I have a package to download a csv from a uri and then transfer it to the database via sqlBulkCopy.
The problem is that the first column is a unix timestamp in the csv but a date time column in the database. The columns are mapped by position so It is always the first column. How can I convert the first csv column from unix timestamp to DateTime in the process of bulk copying it?

my code:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
#endregion

namespace ST_60ba88432cf3439292163e13136c72ea
{
   /// <summary>
   /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
   /// or parent of this class.
   /// </summary>
   [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
   public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
   {
       #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
       /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
        * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
        * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
        * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
        * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
        * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
        * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
        * 
        * Example of reading from a variable:
        *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
        * 
        * Example of writing to a variable:
        *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
        * 
        * Example of reading from a package parameter:
        *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
        *  
        * Example of reading from a project parameter:
        *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
        * 
        * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
        *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
        * */

       #endregion

       #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
       /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
        * 
        * Example of firing an error event:
        *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
        * 
        * Example of firing an information event:
        *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
        * 
        * Example of firing a warning event:
        *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
        * */
       #endregion

       #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
       /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
        * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
        * 
        * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
        *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
        *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
        *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
        *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
        *
        * Example of using a File connection manager
        *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
        *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
        *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
        *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
        * */
       #endregion


       /// <summary>
       /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
       /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
       /// To open Help, press F1.
       /// </summary>
       public void Main()
       {
           // TODO: Add your code here
           string connectionString = Dts.Variables["User::SqlBulkCopyConnection"].Value.ToString();
           string FullFilePath = Dts.Variables["User::FullFilePath"].Value.ToString();
           string Destination = "[dbo].[" + Dts.Variables["User::DestinationTableName"].Value.ToString() + "]";
           GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(FullFilePath, connectionString, Destination);
           Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
       }
        DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path, string connname, string destname)
       {
           bool fireAgain = true;
           Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Create DataTable", "Creation has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain);
           DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
           Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Create DataTable", "Creation has completed", "", 0, ref fireAgain);
           try
           {
               Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Opening file", "File: " + Dts.Variables["User::FullFilePath"].Value.ToString(), "", 0, ref fireAgain);
               using (TextReader csvReader = File.OpenText(csv_file_path))
               {
                   string line;
                   while ((line = csvReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                   {
                       string[] items = line.Trim().Split(',');
                       if (csvData.Columns.Count == 0)
                       {
                           csvData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(items[0], typeof(DateTime)));
                           for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i++)
                           {
                               csvData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(items[i], typeof(float)));
                           }
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           csvData.Rows.Add(items);
                       }
                   }
               }
               Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Creating SQLConnection", "String: " + Dts.Variables["User::SqlBulkCopyConnection"].Value.ToString(), "", 0, ref fireAgain);
               using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connname))
               {
                   Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Open dbConnection", "connecting", "", 0, ref fireAgain);
                   dbConnection.Open();
                   Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Copying Data", "Copying", "", 0, ref fireAgain);
                   using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
                   {
                       s.DestinationTableName = destname;
                       s.WriteToServer(csvData);
                   }
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               // Logging why Upload failed
               Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Upload File", "Upload failed: " + ex.Message, string.Empty, 0);

               // Quit Script Task unsuccesful
               Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
           }
           return csvData;
       }

       #region ScriptResults declaration
       /// <summary>
       /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
       /// result of the script.
       /// 
       /// This code was generated automatically.
       /// </summary>
       enum ScriptResults
       {
           Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
           Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
       };
       #endregion

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leveraged below SO post for converting from unix timestamp to datetime. https://stackoverflow.com/a/250400/634935

```cs
public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime( double unixTimeStamp )
{
    // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds( unixTimeStamp ).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
```

Now, you need to call this function in your code

```
 if (csvData.Columns.Count == 0)
                       {
                           csvData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(items[0], typeof(DateTime)));
                           for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i++)
                           {
                               csvData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(items[i], typeof(float)));
                           }
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           items[0] = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(items[0]); //call function
                           csvData.Rows.Add(items);
                       }
```

Comment: So I tried your solution and it says it is an invalid argument. I tried tweaking the logic but no matter what I do it seems to not be quite correct. sometimes it treats items(0) as a string, others a datetime

Comment: @Nathan, see how items[0] is coming and see if it is getting passed as double. Ideally, it should work.

Comment: items 0 is defined as a string though. Its parsing line data from a csv file. which then gets added to non string table columns.

Comment: @NatanAndrews, please convert the string explicitly to double, before calling the function, `Convert.ToDouble(items[0])` and when return the result, return return `dtDateTime.ToString()`

Comment: Yes, I realized the issue right after I typed that last comment. Sorry for the obvious type mismatch issue. Working late on very little sleep now. Thank you so much. the script now works flawlessly. Thank you so much. Now I can go home and see my wife :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an additional step into your SSIS Package.  Read the source in as VARCHAR values and include a Derived Column task before writing it to the database.

In the Derived Column task you can write the code to convert it between formats.