# Convert int to DateTime in Nest query?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am attempting to query an ES cluster through Nest. However, I'm having an issue because my types are not matching.

This is the C# side:

[image: C#]

As you can see CreatedTimeStamp is a DateTime.

However, this is what I receive in Postman:

[image: Postman]

Where CreatedTimeStamp is now an Int (or Long).

When I run this basic query:

```
var searchResponse = Event.client.Search<mdl.Event>(s => s
                    .From(0)
                    .Size(1000)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .MatchAll()));
```

This is causing the following error:

Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonParsingException : expected:'String Begin Token', actual:'1631555771000', at offset:344

Basically, how can I convert the type from ES to fit the C#?

Comment: It looks like the value may be coming through in unix timestamp format. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Comment: @Jonathan I understand I can use those functions to convert. I'm more specifically wondering how it can be done in the scope of an Elasticsearch query, if it's possible.