# Convert MM dd yyyy to unix timestamp

Tags: c#

Hello guys i am trying to convert the date to UNIX timestamp but i get an error while converting it with some specific dates

```cs
string         zoho_meeting_start_date_time = result.Value<JObject>()["Start_DateTime"].Value<String>();
DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffSet               = DateTimeOffset.Parse(zoho_meeting_start_date_time);

zoho_meeting_start_date_time_timestamp = dateTimeOffSet
    .ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
    .ToString();
```

- When I have the date for example : `"08/01/2022 17:00:00"` it gets converted perfectly fine to  `1641657600000`.
- When I get the date `"07/28/2022 16:00:00"` I get this error:

  > `System.FormatException`: String '`07/28/2022 16:00:00`' was not recognized as a valid `DateTime`.

Comment: see this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 4):

That's because `1641657600000` is Saturday 8th January 2022 and the date string is being interpreted as `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`. Now when you try it with 07/28/2022, 28 is an invalid value for month and the error is thrown.

What you need to do is use `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact` and specify explicitly the format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` as this is not the default.

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(zoho_meeting_start_date_time, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
```

Comment: Why would DateTimeOffset use CurrentCulture? running it on dotnetfiddle seems fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zJDEG3

Comment: Thank you for your help, but is the syntax correct bcs i get an error saying that "No overload for method Parse.Exact takes 2 arguments"

Comment: By default DotNetFiddle use the InvariantCulture if you try flipping it to `28/07/2022` there then you get the same error OP is seeing.

Comment: Nope, sorry. I've updated the code. If you're passing a specific format then You can pass a null IFormatProvider.