# Date format in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display date in my application through jquery but the date format is not in actual format it shows 
**/Date(1337157963000)/** 
how to manage it, i am using **VS2008** thanks.

Comment: What should it print instead? What pattern do you want?

Comment: If you want an answer you're going to have to include some code for us to look at. Hard to know what you're doing wrong if we don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see here
[How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

Your date `/Date(1337157963000)/`  is in JSON format. To be as a date time, you have to convert it to date time

`var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));` (in javascript)

Or for C#, read [How to convert DateTime from JSON to C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249721/how-to-convert-datetime-from-json-to-c)